# Is it possible to find View Model referenced properties

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I'm using Caliburn.Micro for some time now on my project (WPF) and I'm wondering if it is possible to use "Find All Reference" from View Model to get control(s) (button,combobox,textbox) that is referencing property (without going CTRL+F through View)?
I know that there is design time support (http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/design-time) if you want to jump from View to ViewModel but is it possible to jump from View Model to View in similar fashion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not likely since the properties that you bind in your XAML markup to are actually resolved using reflection at *runtime*.

There is at least no built-in support in Visual Studio to do this.

The view model doesn't (and shouldn't) know which elements in the view that may bind to it and the compiler doesn't know either.

For this to work you would need some plugin that tries to resolve the binding paths based on the DataContext at design time (when you initialize the "Find all references" command). Again, Visual Studio doesn't do this.